# iOS Line spacing attribute on NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

How can we set line spacing or line height on NSMutableAttributedString. 
I have tried with

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
[paragraphStyle setLineSpacing:150] ;
paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = 150;
[self addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, self.length)];
```

with No luck.

any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set `paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight`.

I hope it will help!

Comment: I think you have to do this on a whole paragraph (Return before and after). If you do this on text in the middle of a paragraph, it won't work...